# How to type array of array of numbers in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to type array of any number of arrays with 3 coordinates each :

[[1,2,3], [4,5,6],...]

I'd like something like this except it doesn't work

```
Array<Array<Number,Number,Number>>
```

Comment: Array<[number, number, number]>

Comment: An array with fixed length and positional types is called a `tuple` in typescript. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEUC8UDaA7ArgLYBGEiANFASWZdaYgLraMDcAUOwMYD2uAzsCjAIggIwAuWAmRpMObGMoAmSgGZGbbn0HDRwZVLhJU6LNkUr1jStgAslAKyUAbJo68BQkYLVGZpvIWSlCqUBq2Yu5QAPQxUGSIPIjaXnqCdv4mcuaWoda2DlDOUC6UAOzRcQnIyUA)

```
type MyArray = [number, number, number][];

const test1: MyArray = [[1, 2, 3]];
const test2: MyArray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
const test3: MyArray = [[1, 2, 3], [1]]; // error
const test4: MyArray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]; // error
```