# How to type an array of arrays returned from function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm getting the following error:

```
./src/util/util.ts
  Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

It appears to be caused by the following in my util.ts:

```js
export function dateMapEntriesSortedByDate(dateMap: DateMap): [string, number][] {
    return Object.entries(dateMap).sort();
}
```

If I changed [string, number][] to any, it compiles.

I'm using Typescript 4.2.3 and the [following compiles and runs just fine on www.typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBECGpoFlGVgXlgb1gNoDW04AXLAM6gBOAlgHYDmAuhQwK4C2ARtDbAC%20AbhAAzDgwDGoOgHsGsACbI0GAKINadaJQDKcmiiUAhcEhQAKFSnSQKFtZACUFAtXrMANLE69%20LAQseMCwYbA00KAcNIoA8jwAVtAyAHTQWvS61qp2zqmUhqCWzqKC4pIy8orQXJAQjnYlDrkYIeERUTGKuCLA5cBSCtSwXG04tfXmrZAlooPDoMopAEwADACMAJzYCKqpAKoAKgDCluvbPhsrsAC0sBtXPmvPr7Br%20aByetrMcwsMEaJRAMdbrXaOQ6nc5rdZXO4PJ7vN4vd6fb6-Jj-IaApZiaA8MFrCH7Y5nIk%20G73R6I5F01EfVJfH6eLGlEBjSAEfGE2FrYI4a6iTkEJSrTZbAWwADMABZhRgCMDQXypUKQDiRoUjNAlJptLpdjYnPqsvoirqzI5LJz2QDCgAbaCpB1yLHa4ymnSUUpAA):

```js
type DateMap = { [key: string]: number };
function dateMapEntriesSortedByDate(dateMap: DateMap): [string, number][] {
    return Object.entries(dateMap).sort();
}
function emptyDateMap(): DateMap {
    return {};
}
const map = emptyDateMap();
const dec2019 = Date.UTC(2019, 12 - 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toString();
const jan2020 = Date.UTC(2020, 1 - 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toString();
const feb2020 = Date.UTC(2020, 2 - 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toString();
map[feb2020] = 12;
map[dec2019] = 34;
map[jan2020] = 12;
const sortedEntries = dateMapEntriesSortedByDate(map);
console.log(sortedEntries);
```

I also tried typing it with a custom type as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63410848/2848676 but it did not resolve the error.

```js
type MyEntries = [string, number][];

export function dateMapEntriesSortedByDate(dateMap: DateMap): MyEntries {
    return Object.entries(dateMap).sort();
}
```

I also tried simplifying it as suggested in [Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079477/line-0-parsing-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined#comment115079960_62084097) but then it wouldn't even compile:

```js
type MyEntries = [][];
```

Comment: Sounds like a dependency issue, not an issue with your code

Comment: @CertainPerformance maybe typescript-eslint?  I see that mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40446.  However typescript-eslint isn't in my package.json so I don't know how to control its version.

Comment: I'd try deleting your package-lock.json, deleting your node_modules, updating all entries in your package.json to the latest version, then reinstalling all the modules. Might fix it.

Comment: A good trick I like using is going into the node_modules directory and checking out the package.json there. Does it match the same version? If it does, some deps use a particular subdependency so that may be your problem. In which case, devDependencies/peerDependencies/resolutions in your package.json may solve the issue

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance I'm still having the problem.  I tried deleting my yarn.lock (I have that instead of package-lock.json), deleted my node_modules, ran `yarn upgrade` then `yarn install` but I can still reproduce the problem.  I lack a lot of background knowledge on TypeScript and JavaScript so any other hints you can think of, please let me knows.

Comment: @Dom thank you.  When you say to go into a package.json under node_modules and check the version, are you talking about the version of typescript-eslint?  Sorry I'm not more knowledgeable about TypeScript or even JavaScript.  I appreciate any pointers or tips.

Comment: What is the current version of `@typescript-eslint/parser `. As depicted by @Dom, please find `@typescript-eslint/parser ` in the node_modules and note its version.

Comment: @ShivamSingla it says `"version": "2.34.0"` in the package.json of the file node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser/package.json in my project.  So I ran `yarn add  @typescript-eslint/parser --dev` which added `"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.21.0"` to my `devDependencies` in my package.json.  Still getting the error though.  I confirmed node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser/package.json is version 4.21.0.